# Problemas de CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

Estou com a seguinte função *JQuery* para mudar o tamanho da fonte durante o Redimensionamento de tela.

```
const textPattern = 0.0085;
function resizeFont(widthWindow){
    var calc_text = widthWindow * textPattern;
    $('body').css('font-size', calc_text);
}
```

O problema que ao usar essa função o todas as bordas aumentam proporcionalmente e eu não queria isso, tentei consertar isso, alterando a função dessa forma

```
var width = $(window).width();    
const textPattern = 0.0085;
function resizeFont(widthWindow){
    var calc_text = widthWindow * textPattern;
    var calc_exception = width * textPattern;
    $('body').css('font-size', calc_text);
    $('input').css('font-size', calc_exception);
}
```

Testei esta função na minha tela de login onde as bordas dos inputs estavam aumentando mas não surtiu efeito, alguém saberia me dizer como consertar isso?

Comment: Como é que ocorre o redimensionamento da tela? estás a pensar em mobile com ecrã horizontal e vertical? senão podias fazer isso somente com CSS...

Comment: estou fazendo só para WEB mesmo, e estou fazendo via Jquery pois queria deixar todas as minhas fontes no texto em um tamanho certo para o seu elemento quando fosse haver o redimensionamento, se não tiver essa função acabam que as fontes estouram o tamanho dos elementos e acabam saindo fora da TAG

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo com um jsFiddle do problema?

Comment: Usa media queries no CSS, é bem mais fácil que da forma como esta fazendo.

Comment: Você poderia criar um exemplo no JSFiddle, na própria ferramenta do site ou, ainda, descrever melhor qual o problema que você está tentando corrigir?

Comment: Jonathan eu acho q talvez você não tenha entendido, o meu site não vai abranger dispositivos moveis e sim só computadores de uma intranet de computadores, o que eu quero é fazer ele se adaptar a varios tipos de resolução e pelo que eu pesquisei sobre media queries, o uso dele esta mais ligado a adaptação mobile.

Comment: Não é apenas para mobile @MiguelCarigo, pelo contrário, é muito mais simples para o que você precisa e serve para tratar quaisquer resoluções, é diretamente ligado ao mobile pelo fato de ser muito utilizado para esse fim, mas não se limita ao mobile...de forma alguma...

Comment: @MiguelCarigo, eu altamente te aconselho a usar o Media Query do CSS, pelo simples fato de que ele foi feito para o browser saber fazer essas modificações de layout para diferentes resoluções, independente da plataforma. Fazer isso via Javascript é uma ideia ruim, pois você vai estar reescrevendo uma coisa que o browser já sabe fazer nativamente e, dependendo da forma que você fizer isso, você vai ter uma quebra de performance, entre outros possíveis problemas.

Comment: @MiguelCarigo, aqui vai uma dica: os seus usuários vão sim querer acessar o seu site via mobile, afinal, hoje 51% dos acessos a internet são feitos via mobile e esse numero cresce todo dia.
http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/2016/11/01/mobile-web-usage-overtakes-desktop-for-first-time/